# Switch spaces trackpad MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook, touchpad, osx-spaces

I want to be able to change spaces by swiping.

Example:

- Swiping right would switch to the space to the right
- Swiping down would switch to the space underneath

I tried [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) but it only enables me to see all spaces, not switch between them.

Anybody know a way, or if this is even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jitouch](http://www.jitouch.com/index.php?page=jitouch) allows this. The gesture used is customizable, and it includes a large number of other possible gestures as well. (It's not in the picture, but *n*-finger swipes are possible gestures).  Aside from Exposé, Jitouch is my favorite usability utility; any time I'm on another computer and I can't gesture to close tabs and windows, I cry a little inside.

If you have a Magic Mouse, Jitouch also lets you input gestures on its surface as well.

[image: Jitouch preferences page]

Comment: @Veltar: Glad to help. If this answers your question sufficiently, please check the hollow checkmark next to the answer to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite a gesture but close enough: [Warp](http://www.ksuther.com/warp/) makes the screen edges sensitive to a mouse-touch and presents an image of the adjacent space.  Clicking in the image, or optionally, just dwelling in it, changes to that space.  Works equally well with a mouse or a trackpad.